# SQL between date with dd.mm.yyyy only matches on day

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to use a Datepicker to select specific entries in my Database.

The Problem i face is that the entries i get as a reposnse from my query are only sorted for the day part of the date.

I use the date format (varchar field in database):

```
*dd.mm.yyyy hh:mm ($date = date("Y-m-d") . ' ' . date("H:i");)*
```

For example:

```
 01.04.2016
 10.04.2016
 11.04.2016
 01.04.2017
 10.04.2017
 11.04.2017
```

The Query to get the entries:

```
SELECT *
FROM order_date
WHERE date >= '10.04.2017' AND date <= '10.04.2017'
```

Now i expected to get only the to matching entries but
the result of the Query are all four table entries which start with day 10 or 11. Even two of them are in the year 2016.

As i saw in other posts the *between XX and YY* work if the date is set with yyyy-mm-dd or yyyymmdd but the problem is that i got a database with around 20k entries on which i need a datepicker so i would prefer to use the givin format of the date without rewriting all entries.

Is there a possibilty to get a datepicker between with dd.mm.yyyy format aswell?

Any help highly appriciated

Comment: Fixing the database is easier than you think.  Add a new column with a datatype of `date`.  Update it from your existing column.  Update all references to the existing column, then drop it from the table.

Comment: the idea with a new column and updating / changing it around is realy nice but the problem is that the data is used in different locations so i cant just change the format without replacing it on a few different places as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this,

```
STR_TO_DATE('10.04.2017', '%d.%m.%Y')

SELECT *
FROM order_date
WHERE date >= STR_TO_DATE('10.04.2017', '%d.%m.%Y') AND date <= STR_TO_DATE('10.04.2017', '%d.%m.%Y')
```

Comment: thank you for your help but i use this on my databse im only getting an empty result so far.

Comment: had to modify a bit of the data but could keep my format dd.mm.yyyy with the STR_TO_DATE. thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can typecast the column as DATE, and use the ORDER BY clause.

Answer (score 1):

Use [STR_TO_DATE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) function may help.

```
STR_TO_DATE('10.04.2017','%d.%m.%Y')
```

Answer (score 1):

How about something around this idea ?

```
SELECT * 
FROM Mytable WHERE date
                 BETWEEN CONVERT(datetime,'10.04.2017',104 ) 
                     AND CONVERT(datetime,'10.04.2017',104 )
```

Comment: thank you for your help. i jused tried this in the database but it tells #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''10.04.2017',106 ) 
                     AND CONVERT(datetime,'10.04.2017',106 )' at line 3 -- im not realy sure if i can use CONVERT() on a mysql database

Comment: In MySQL, the arguments of the `CONVERT` seem to be inverted, so it's `CONVERT('10.04.2017', datetime)`. But you can't specify the date style unfortunatly so it doesn't answer your problem. I think `STR_TO_DATE` is the way to go, as others pointed out.